# "Checked" status of checkboxes mapped from prop array aren't matching array.find results with second array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I have an object called `props.currentEditorGroup` and an array of objects called `props.contacts`. My component displays a checkbox for each `contact` in the contacts array. If there is a contact in `props.currentEditorGroup` with the same id as a contact in `props.contacts`, then the `checked` value should be `true`. instead the checkbox for each contact is marked as `false`, and clicking on the checkbox doesn't "check" the box.
However, clicking on a checkbox will still add a contact to `props.currentEditorGroup` if the contact doesn't have a matching id, or remove the contact if it does.

```
{props.contacts.map(contact => (
                    <div className="mb-3" key={contact.id}>
                        <Form.Check 
                            onChange={handleCheckbox}
                            type='checkbox'
                            label={`${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}`}
                            value={contact.id}
                            checked={props.currentEditorGroup.groupContacts.find(
                                    groupContact => (groupContact.id === contact.id)) ? true : false
                            }
                        />
                    </div>
                ))}
```

This is handleCheckbox, which triggers when the checkbox component is clicked.

````
const handleCheckbox = event => {
        const { value } = event.target;
        console.log(value);
        const intValue = parseInt(value, 10);
        let editorGroupContacts = [...props.currentEditorGroup.groupContacts];

        //Making Adjustments
        const contactExists = editorGroupContacts.find(contactId => contactId === intValue);

        if (contactExists) {
          editorGroupContacts = editorGroupContacts.filter(contactId => contactId !== intValue);
        } 
        else {
          const contact = intValue;
          editorGroupContacts = [...editorGroupContacts, contact];
        }

        props.setCurrentEditorGroup({...props.currentEditorGroup, groupContacts: editorGroupContacts });
    }
    ```
````

Comment: can you console.log(groupContact) in props.currentEditorGroup.groupContacts.find( before returning (groupContact.id === contact.id)? And show us, what groupContact  looks like?

Comment: @Domino987 What would the syntax for that look like?

Comment: Please use `some` function instead of `find`.

Comment: @Domino987 I changed the line to 
```
checked={props.currentEditorGroup.groupContacts.find(
                                    groupContact => {
                                        console.log(groupContact)
                                        return (groupContact.id === contact.id)
                                    } ) ? true : false
                            }
```
The contact group has 2 contacts. The `console.log` printed:
1
2
1
2

Comment: @Antonio I changed it from `.find` to `.some` and it netted the same results. I added `console.log(groupContact.id === contact.id)` before the `.find` return, which reveals that I'm returning false for each contact in the group.

Comment: I think you save groupContact as the is and not the whole contact, that is why console log prints 1,2,1,2 . Remove the id from groupContact.id and it should work.